# pass array of emails to Job class Mail::to

Tags: php, arrays, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am able to send single email but when it comes to multiple emails jobs class fails to send it to multiple users.

The code below works fine and sends email to one user

```
$email = new Report($this->user);
Mail::to($this->user->email)->queue($email);
```

Even hard-coding the email works too

```
$email = new Report($this->user);
Mail::to("example@hello.com")->queue($email);
```

But when I pass multiple or array of emails Job fail:

```
$email = new Report($this->user);
$all_admin = User::select('email')->where('role',2)->get()->pluck('email')->toArray();
$all_admins = json_encode($all_admin, true);
Mail::to($all_admins )->queue($email);
```

This code is written in App\Jobs\ReportAdmin file in handle function.

I have sent before array of emails without using jobs

something like:

```
Mail::send('emails.report', ['firstname'=>$firstname,'lastname'=>$lastname], function ($message)
        {
            $message->from('hello@example.com', 'auto-reply email');
            $message->to($all_admins);
            $message->subject('subject');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc

> To send a message, use the to method on the Mail facade. The to method accepts an email address, a user instance, or a collection of users.

So do this.

```
$email = new Report($this->user);

$admins = User::select('email')->where('role', 2)->get();

Mail::to($admins)->queue($email);
```

This is what happens under the hood. In case you want to use different ways to load the email list.

```
public function to($address, $name = null)
{
    return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'to');
}

protected function setAddress($address, $name = null, $property = 'to')
{
    foreach ($this->addressesToArray($address, $name) as $recipient) {
        $recipient = $this->normalizeRecipient($recipient);

        $this->{$property}[] = [
            'name' => isset($recipient->name) ? $recipient->name : null,
            'address' => $recipient->email,
        ];
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function addressesToArray($address, $name)
{
    if (! is_array($address) && ! $address instanceof Collection) {
        $address = is_string($name) ? [['name' => $name, 'email' => $address]] : [$address];
    }

    return $address;
}

protected function normalizeRecipient($recipient)
{
    if (is_array($recipient)) {
        return (object) $recipient;
    } elseif (is_string($recipient)) {
        return (object) ['email' => $recipient];
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried at first. but whenever its array mail cannot be sent and I can observer in Database attempts increasing and Jobs being processed when I listen to the queue.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia i'm sending the user object collection, not the array

Comment: Oh okay. I will test and see

Comment: my bad it works. I guess I never tried without toArray(). Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
$all_admins = json_encode($all_admin, true);
```

for that:

```
$all_admins = implode(';', $all_admin);
```

This should give you a valid  string format.

**EDIT**

You can also give a try with itteration:

```
$email = new Report($this->user);
$all_admin = User::select('email')->where('role',2)->get()
    ->pluck('email')->toArray();
$all_admins = json_encode($all_admin, true);
foreach ($all_admin as $admin) {
    Mail::to($admin)->queue($email);
}
```

This is even better solution because each e-mail will be send by a single job.

Comment: Ok. I found another one - I've reedit my entry, you can check now

Answer (score 0):

I used a for loop and it works.

Don't know if its the best way to approach this problem.

```
/**
  * Execute the job.
  *
  * @return void
  */
public function handle()
{
    $email = new Report($this->user);
    $all_admin = User::select('email')->where('role',2)->get()->pluck('email')->toArray();
    $count = count($all_admin);
    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        Mail::to($all_admin[$i])->queue($email);
    }
}
```